# Web request returns wrong data when the code is executed on a browser

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm trying to develop a WebExtension that uses Youtube and Spotify APIs. But I have a problem with the last part of the Youtube code. I need to obtain the artist and song data from Youtube, and this fields aren't returned by Youtube API, so I need to make an specific request . https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core can be used to do that.

The code is working when I execute it using Node directly, but if I try to do it directly on a web browser, the response is strange. In browser, the response is a JSON like this: `{ reload: now }`

So I've tried to do it without the extension, and I've used Postman to check the response too. Using Postman is correct, the response is the expected, but I don't know why the browser doesn't give me the correct response. It gives me again the JSON `{ reload: now }` and sometimes, it gives me a complete HTML response.

The code without using the module is this:

```js
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("x-youtube-client-name", "1");
    myHeaders.append("x-youtube-client-version", "2.20191008.04.01");
    myHeaders.append("Host", "www.youtube.com");
    myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: myHeaders,
      referrerPolicy: "no-referrer"
    };

    fetch("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PS5jAMkCmU&hl=en&bpctr=1590268069&pbj=1", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

[image]

Using the module:

```
ytdl.getInfo(ids_array[i], (err, info) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(info);
});
```

I don't understand why the browser is producing a wrong response. Here is the request using Postman:

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes @Casper. The bug was notified to the author of the lib, and was fixed a few weeks ago. The problem was the cookie header. The browser includes it on any request, and it causes the bug. If you force the browser not to add this cookie header, all works flawlessly. This is the link to the specific commit that fixes it: https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/commit/499eb63915fba7c3b8cf55cce48b057b0b3c824f